# Patterns in a key generation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, reverse-engineering, key-generator

I want to reverse-engineer a key generation algorithm which starts from a 4-byte ID, and the output is a 4-byte key. This seems to not be impossible or very difficult, because some patterns can be observed. In the following picture are the inputs and outputs of the algorithm for 8 situations: 
[image]

As it can be seen, if the bytes from inputs are matching, also the outputs are matching, but with some exceptions (the red marking in the image).

So I think there are some simple arithmetic/binary operations done, and the mismatch could come from a carry of an addition operation.

Until now I ran a C program with some simple operations on the least significant byte of the inputs, with up to 4 variable parameters (0..255, all combinations) and compared with the output LSB, but without success.

Could you please advise me, what else could I try? And what do you think, it's possible what I'm trying to do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So you have access to calling the generation algorithm with any 4-byte sequence? If that is the case then it would be very easy to for example verify whether there is cross byte correlation

Comment: No, I don't have access to the algorithm. I could get some more samples, but I cannot control the input sequence to get the corresponding output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I want to migrate it to http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ but seems it's too old to do this. I'll probably post it again on that site.